# Socket io connection not established with express node js, console log does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Trying to connect to socket io through a separate chat page tab and not with index.html, but not able to connect. I do not want the chat page to be the home page. Server and client console log does not work either. This only console logs "*Express app listening at http://localhost:8888*" but not "New WS Connection".

**Server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const axios = require('axios');
const port = 8888 || process.env.PORT;

const socketio = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUsersInRoom } = require('./users');
const router = require('./router');
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use(cors());
app.use(router);

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join', ({ name, room }, callback) => {
    console.log('New WS Connection...');
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name, room });

    if(error) return callback(error);

    socket.join(user.room);

    socket.emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name}, welcome to room ${user.room}.`});
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has joined!` });

    io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room) });

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: user.name, text: message });

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);

    if(user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'Admin', text: `${user.name} has left.` });
      io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)});
    }
  })
});


server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log(`Express app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('server is up and running');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**chat.js on client side**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from "socket.io-client";
import './Chat.css';
import InfoBar from '../InfoBar/InfoBar';
import Input from '../Input/Input';
import Messages from '../Messages/Messages';
import TextContainer from '../TextContainer/TextContainer';

let socket;

export default function Chat({ location }) {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState('');

    const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:8888/';

    useEffect(() => {
        const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

        socket = io(ENDPOINT);

        console.log(name, room);
        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);

        socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (error) => {
            if(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', (message) => {
            setMessages(messages => [...messages, message]);
        });

        socket.on('roomData', ({ users }) => {
            setUsers(users);
        });
    }, []);

   const sendMessage = (event) => {
       event.preventDefault();

       if(message){
        socket.emit('sendMessage', message, () => setMessage(''));
       } 
   }

//    console.log(message, messages);

    return (
        <div className="outerContainer">
            <div className="container">
                <InfoBar room={room}/>
                <Messages messages={messages} name={name}/>
                <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage} />
            </div>
            <TextContainer users={users} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello,
Please pass socketio in connect time

ex

io.on('connect', (socketio ) => {

}

or you can try


io.sockets.on('connect', function (socketio ) {

}